# Can a directory on a website contain a period in its name?

Tags: url, directory

Is it possible for a folder on a website to have a name that contains a period? For example, is "foo.folder" a valid directory name on a website?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes. **all legal filenames are allowed**. characters that cannot be transfered via http will be `urlencoded` but the dot is not one of them.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is yes.
This has been used in scam a lot and it's still working.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how is this used for scamming?

Comment: here is an example:
you make a folder called picture.jpg
you add a index.php in that folder and pun an image on that page.
you then post the link on wordpress sites in the comments section and the admin is going to validate it cause he will believe it's a link to a picture.
after you get your link validated, you can delete the index.php and replace it with a page containing links. this way you can create backlinks to your websites.

there are some slight variations that can be used to get admin access to the site if you mix in some xss.

Comment: website.com/scam.exe <- a directory